# Array diff implementation in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

Does anybody know of an array diff implementation in PHP? I need to use this to develop a feature similar to the way stackexchange diffs tags.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: For Array functions you can refer this link :http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp

Answer (score 1):

Like the documentation says:

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

For example:

```
 $array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
 $array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
 $result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

Would end up with `$result` containing only the value `blue`, because it is only in one of the arrays.

Complete documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

There is array_diff which will compare the values of 2 arrays and return an array with values of the differences.

```
$arrayone = array("bacon" => "tasty", "lettuce", "carrot");
$arraytwo = array("ham" => "tasty", "carrot");

$differences = array_diff($arrayone, $arraytwo);
var_dump($differences);
$differences = array_diff($arraytwo, $arrayone);
var_dump($differences);
```

This will give:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'lettuce' (length=7)

array (size=0)
  empty
```

One important thing is it only goes one way the first array is compared to the other ones passed.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php